# Attribute center print to console pygame

Tags: python, printing, pygame

I am trying to print to the console in pygame, and here:

```
def drawPressKeyMsg(self):
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 18)
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render("Press a key to play.", True, DARK_GREY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOW_WIDTH - 200, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 30)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)
```

I am able to use the .topleft but later in the code:

```
def showMenuScreen(self):
    menuFont = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 100)
    optionFont = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 50)
    menuSurf = menuFont.render("PONG GAME", True, WHITE, TURQUOISE)
    option1Surf = optionFont.render("Press 1 to play the game!", True, WHITE, TURQUOISE)
    option2Surf = optionFont.render("Press 2 to exit!", True, WHITE, TURQUOISE)
    menuRect = menuSurf.get_rect
    option1Rect = option1Surf.get_rect
    option2Rect = option2Surf.get_rect

    menuRect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2)
    option1Rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - 25)
    option2Rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - 50)

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(menuSurf, menuRect)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(option1Surf, option1Rect)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(option2Surf, option2Rect)
```

the .center displays the error "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'center'"

Comment: always show full error message (traceback) - there are other usefull information. For example it shows which line makes problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `()` in all `get_rect()` so it doesn't return `Rect` which have `center` but it returns reference to method `get_rect` and reference doesn't have `center`